# MySql cell subvalues from not atomic, serialized data cell

Tags: mysql, sql, select, drupal, drupal-7

In Drupal there is a log table where in one cell there are multiple values stored as one string like:

```
a:2:{s:5:"%name";s:20:"qwertyuiopasdfghjklm";s:6:"%email";s:23:"qwertyuiopasd@yahoo.com";}
```

How would I get just email address from this cell using sql query ?

Comment: select all records from table, unserialize, then take email from array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that with multiple calls of SUBSTRING_INDEX like that:

```
SET @a = 'a:2:{s:5:"%name";s:20:"qwertyuiopasdfghjklm";s:6:"%email";s:23:"qwertyuiopasd@yahoo.com";}';
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(
        SUBSTRING_INDEX(
            @a, '"%email"', -1
        ), '"', -2
    ), '"', 1
);
```

**Explanation:**

- The innermost call returns all after the search string '"%email"'
  in the example: `;s:23:"qwertyuiopasd@yahoo.com";}`
- The middle one returns all after the beginning double quote before the email address from that:
  `qwertyuiopasd@yahoo.com";}`
- and the outer one removes the trailing rest of the string including the last double quote:
  `qwertyuiopasd@yahoo.com`

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/316d8/1)